# Comparing namespaces to see if they match

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am trying to compare namespaces to see if my method only throws the correct exceptions. With the correct exceptions I mean the following:

1. Exceptions from the same namespace.
2. Exceptions from a higher namespace.
3. Exceptions from equivalent (and higher) System-namespace.

Examples:

1. Method is in namespace `MyNamespace.Collections.Generic` so it can throw exceptions from `MyNamespace.Collections.Generic`.
2. Method is in namespace `MyNamespace.Collections.Generic` so it can throw exceptions from `MyNamespace.Collections` and `MyNamespace`.
3. Method is in namespace `MyNamespace.Collections.Generic` so it can throw exceptions from `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Collections` and `System`.

The first part is quite easy; checking for the same namespace. Also one part of number 3 worked; because `System` namespace is always correct.

For the other parts I tried the following:

```
string[] exceptNamespaceSegments = exceptionNamespaceSegments
                                   .Except(classNamespaceSegments)
                                   .ToArray();

if (exceptNamespaceSegments.Length == 1 && exceptNamespaceSegments.FirstOrDefault() == "System")
    return;
```

Which checks if the namespace-segments (Collections, Generic) are also used in the class-namespace. If this is the case, the correct exception is thrown.

But this wouldn't work for a case where the exception is in namespace `System.Collections.Generic.Something`, because `Something` isn't in the class-namespace.

Come to think of it, this doesn't take into account the sequence. So `System.Generic.Collections` would also be correct; using what I currently have.

Is there any way I can get this done without having to write a butload of if-statements comparing each individual segment?

Comment: Curious: Why are you doing this? What's wrong with throwing exceptions from another namespace?

Comment: One of the cases that we looked at was a situation where a class `List<T>` threw a `FileNotFoundException`, which obviously shouldn't happen. So we decided on this rule, with a few exceptions (haha) here and there.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I actually wrote that 5 minutes ago! Sorry :(

Comment: List<T> does not throw a FileNotFoundException (except regarding serialization perhaps). Perhaps an object stored in List<T> does. But then, checking which exceptions can be thrown by methods of List<T> is the wrong thing to do...

Comment: @Matthijs That's fine, but I answerd 15 min ago.. I deleted my answer, will undelete if you're interested.. :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I was actually going to accept that answer nonetheless! After looking at your answer, I still thought it could be less complicated; after some thinking and more trying it suddenly hit me!

Comment: @elgonzo: It was more of an example-case to show why we want to check on such cases. A FileNotFoundException from a class as List<T> should surely raise some questions in your head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question: You may try something like this to find all allowed namespaces as per the criteria given.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllowedNamespaces(Type type)
{
    const string System = "System";
    string thisNamespace = type.Namespace;
    HashSet<string> hashset = new HashSet<string>();
    hashset.Add(thisNamespace);
    hashset.Add(System);
    var parts = thisNamespace.Split('.');
    if (parts.Length > 1)
    {
        string previous = string.Empty;
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            var current = string.IsNullOrEmpty(previous)
                ? part
                : string.Format("{0}.{1}", previous, part);
            previous = current;
            hashset.Add(current);
        }

        previous = string.Empty;
        foreach (var part in new[] { System  }.Concat(parts.Skip(1)))
        {
            var current = string.IsNullOrEmpty(previous)
                ? part
                : string.Format("{0}.{1}", previous, part);
            previous = current;
            hashset.Add(current);
        }
    }

    return hashset;
}
```

Then you can easily check whether exception's namespace fall in this list, if not there is a problem :)

There is duplicate code block, you may refactor it to a method to follow DRY principle..

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but I think this is kind of overcomplicating things. Actually wrote a solution that seems to work correctly, see here: http://pastebin.com/VfK6MdPz